# How to position an element on another responsive element?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive, positioning

I have a responsive image that increases size with the browser window. I also am planning on putting icons on this image(which is a map) in the correct locations. I would usually use position absolute and position the elements according to the image's surrounding div which has relative positioning.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm asking? The icons need to be positioned in css/jquery (not part of the image) as I'm planning on having them light up/change color upon mousever

Comment: Please share some code of what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `position: absolute` and specify your `top`/`left`/`bottom`/`right` attributes as a percentage. Another way is to use units like `vw` or `vh` instead of `px`.